# Fluid pressure sensor choice

Tags: sensor, pressure

I need to measure change in pressures in the range of 400-600 Pa. The sensors easily available are in the MPa range, for example 1.2 MPa. I was hoping to acquire a sensor in the upper limit of 1 kPa, but it isn't easily available. If I build an amplification circuit for the analog output, can I measure the minute pressure changes between 400-600 Pa? Is it a good idea?

[Here's](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Water_Pressure_Sensor_SKU__SEN0257) the pressure sensor link.

Comment: Welcome! Depends on the sensor. Please add a link to it.

Comment: Do you want absolute pressure (vacuum reference) or differential pressure (between two ports). Makes a big difference when you want to measure 1 kPa, and atmospheric pressure is 100 kPa.

Comment: @winny added to question

Comment: @Neil_UK its against the atmosphere.

Comment: Have a look for pressure sensors that are slightly less easily available, that have a full scale closer to the range you want to measure. While you could make electronics that have noise and zero drift for the range you want, the sensor itself will compromise reading those small changes. What noise level and zero drift do you want within that 1 kPA range? You don't have to look all that hard to find pressure sensors with much smaller ranges, both on auction sites and on proper suppliers like Digikey and Mouser